# Laravel 5.5 doesn't recognise ?? when using php artisan key:generate

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've been trying to use php artisan key:generate after cloning my Laravel project to a server. However, I get the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/user/public_html/Score-Keeper/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233`

Opening the website shows the Laravel error: `RuntimeException. No application encryption key has been specified.`

I've searched forums for similar issues and noticed most people had the error with Laravel 5.5 and fixed it by upgrading to PHP7. However, I've been using PHP7 both locally and on the server for several months now (also made a phpinfo file to confirm PHP7 is running on this site).

The line of code the error message refers to is the return statement below.

`return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);`

UPDATE:
I ran php -v on the server and it said it's PHP 5.6.31 (cli). I'm assuming the PHP 7 I was using was only for the website (set in an .htaccess file) rather than the cli. Is it possible to update the cli to use PHP7 on shared  hosting? The only examples I can find for linux require sudo

UPDATE 2 (SOLUTION):
After discovering the cli was using PHP 5.6, I contacted the host and they said the following:

> The PHP version for the "php" alias cannot be updated, but you can use the path to the PHP-CLI binary to use any PHP version you need, for example: `/usr/local/php70/bin/php-cli`

So instead of `php artisan`, I used `/usr/local/php71/bin/php-cli artisan migrate` and this fixed the problem.

Comment: You would only get that error if you're not running php7, on cli run `php -v` and paste it in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question

Comment: Both web and artisan/cli require >=7 - If it's shared hosting you need to ask your host why its only 5.6 on the cli and not 7. You can do `php -c /path/to/php.ini  artisan ...` but I dont think that will help.

Comment: what type of linux do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using php 7.1 or php 7.2.4 which works perfectly for me.